# Overlaying Adobe Air 2 with Adobe Air 17

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe, flash-cs5

I have been using adobe flash CS5 with adobe air 2.0, and I want to use air 17 the newest version, I have been having trouble finding out how to do this because all the tutorials online overlay 2.6 with a newer version. In version 2.0 there is no air for android only air for ios so I cannot update the android.xml file that is mentioned in most tutorials. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Download latest AIR from [Adobe labs.](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/air.html) or from [here.](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html)

Once it downloaded, extract in a right place, then open Flash -> navigate to Help -> Manage Adobe AIR SDK.
[image: Help menu]

On the popup window, Click the plus(+) button from the right side,
[image: Pop up dialog]

And locate the extracted folder.

Comment: I am using Adobe Flash CS5 so there is no option to manage sdk's

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/enable-the-latest-air-sdk-in-flash-professional-cs55--active-11488

Comment: My problem is that I don't have an android.xml file because air 2.0 does not support android.